# How do implement d3 v3 brush by specifying a increment brush slide value in steps programmatically

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement the brush behavior as in this example. This example is in d3v4.

URL: https://bl.ocks.org/alexmacy/eb284831aff6f9d0119b

We mention this below line. So the difference between the two is always 30 when you slide:

```
brush.move(brushg, [20, 50].map(x));
```

My query is: can we do the same in d3v3 and what I require is the 30 difference what we are getting initially on the page load should be set programmatically. I mean the difference value eg: 30,20 etc

Also, consider another example with dates (start and end date) when we slide - the increment has to be in steps of the configured value that is what value we specify programmatically.

Suppose: we specify step value as 5 and

> startdate: 11/25/2019 10:00:00 AM,  enddate: 11/25/2019 10:30:00 AM

Now when we slide the slider, the values should be in seconds as:

> 10:00:05 am, 10:00:10 am, 10:00:15 am, 10:00:20 am, 10:00:25 am, 10:00:30 am

step value as 2 then

> 10:00:02 am, 10:00:04 am, 10:00:06 am, 10:00:08 am, 10:00:10 am, 10:00:12 am ...

By default the step value is 1

Iam using d3v3, for specifying domain & range:

```
textScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([startDate, endDate]).range([0, main_width]).clamp(true);
var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.textScale).orient('Bottom');
```

I am implementing in d3v3.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but in case someone came across this issue for D3 v3:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([0, width]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(x)
  .extent([20, 50]);

var svg = d3.select("#slider").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(5)
          .tickFormat(d3.format("")));

var brushg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);

brush.on('brush', function() {brushed()})

d3.select('#start-number')
  .append('text')
  .text(brush.extent()[0]);

d3.select('#end-number')
  .append('text')
  .text(brush.extent()[1]);

function brushed() {
  d3.select('#start-number')
    .text(Math.round(brush.extent()[0]));
  d3.select('#end-number')
    .text(Math.round(brush.extent()[1]));
}

brushed();
```

```css
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  .brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .125;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <body>
    <div id='numbers'>
      <span id='start-number'></span> to <span id='end-number'>
      </span>
    </div> 
    <div id='slider' style="margin-top:1%"></div>
   <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

For the date slider, it's not implemented same as described above in the question but a place to start from, here:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 20;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date('11/25/2019 10:00:00 AM'), new Date('11/25/2019 10:30:00 AM')])
  .nice(d3.time.second)
  .range([0, width]);



var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(x)
  .extent([new Date('11/25/2019 10:10:00 AM'), new Date('11/25/2019 10:15:00 AM')]);

var svg = d3.select("#slider").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(10)
          .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"))
          );

var brushg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);

brush.on('brush', function() {brushed()})


var format = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");



d3.select('#start-number')
  .append('text')
  .text(format(brush.extent()[0]));

d3.select('#end-number')
  .append('text')
  .text(format(brush.extent()[1]));

function brushed() {
  d3.select('#start-number')
    .text(format(brush.extent()[0]));
  d3.select('#end-number')
    .text(format(brush.extent()[1]));
}

brushed();
```

```css
 .axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  .brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .125;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <body>
    <div id='numbers'>
      <span id='start-number'></span> to <span id='end-number'>
      </span>
    </div> 
    <div id='slider' style="margin-top:1%"></div>
   <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```